# how to get soundcloud audio download url by using audio file id

Tags: android, json, audio, soundcloud

am using sound cloud search api. when i hit the search url it give me search results. every audio has stream url but not download url because it depends on setting of the uploader. Every none downloadable file also has download count more than 1. for example, when you'll hit this url

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=4346c8125f4f5c40ad666bacd8e96498&q=tere%20bin&limit=1

It'll give the search result like that

```
[{"kind":"track","id":63225776,"created_at":"2012/10/13 01:52:38 +0000","user_id":26029726,"duration":206177,"commentable":true,"state":"finished","original_content_size":3298521,"last_modified":"2014/10/01 18:56:25 +0000","sharing":"public","tag_list":"","permalink":"tere-bin-uzair-jaswal-official","streamable":true,"embeddable_by":"all","downloadable":false,"purchase_url":null,"label_id":null,"purchase_title":null,"genre":"Musical","title":"Tere Bin - Uzair Jaswal [Official Music Audio]","description":"","label_name":"","release":"","track_type":"original","key_signature":"","isrc":"","video_url":null,"bpm":null,"release_year":null,"release_month":null,"release_day":null,"original_format":"mp3","license":"all-rights-reserved","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/63225776","user":{"id":26029726,"kind":"user","permalink":"uzair-jaswal-1","username":"Uzair Jaswal Music","last_modified":"2014/10/19 13:06:28 +0000","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/26029726","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/uzair-jaswal-1","avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000110064166-2ts508-large.jpg"},"permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/uzair-jaswal-1/tere-bin-uzair-jaswal-official","artwork_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000032079002-kup6vc-large.jpg","waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/9bwAsZfGrxwN_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/63225776/stream","playback_count":359588,"download_count":100,"favoritings_count":7557,"comment_count":491,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/63225776/attachments","policy":"ALLOW"}]
```

this is for only one audio and that audio is not downloadable but it has download count of 100. how is this possible ?
can anybody tell me how i can download that audio which is not downloadable?
any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe it was originally posted as downloadable and the setting was changed later by the uploader ?

Comment: is there any way to download non downloadable audio file?

Comment: I certainly hope it's not :) What would be the point for a user to set the file as not downloadable if anyone could still download it when using the API ?

Comment: Thanks dude, the stream url is also a download url for android. am using it and it is working :)

Comment: if you can access the stream url, offer that as download. i guess normal accounts have these download limit, me too >> check that link https://soundcloud.com/bnzlovesyou/she-is-like-the-wind

Comment: @2Dee check out my answer dude, I'v described it in details that how it works.

Comment: @bnz check out my answer dude, I'v described it in details that how it works.

Comment: your answer says what i mentioned. if you have an account you dont pay for, you will have a dl limit, set to 100. if this is reached, you can only offer the stream. sure, that this does not affect the dl count, because the dl-file is the original one you upload to soundcloud, the stream is processed one, limited to 96 or 128 kbit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fix it myself, i was using android and the stream url is also a download url. the stream url is also download url for downloading but it won't affect on download count. you can try like that

```
String file_url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/93216523/stream?client_id=4346c8125f4f5c40ad666bacd8e96498";
```

pass this url to asyntack and manage you download there, you can pass it like that

```
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
```

here is DownloadFileFromUR class using asyntask

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            URL u = null;
            InputStream is = null;  

                 try {
                          u = new URL(f_url[0]);
                          is = u.openStream(); 
                          HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();//to know the size of video
                          int size = huc.getContentLength();                 

                      if(huc != null){
                          String fileName = "FILE2.mp3";
                          String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                          File f = new File(storagePath,fileName);

                          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                          long total = 0;
                          int len1 = 0;
                          if(is != null){
                             while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                 total+=len1;
                                 publishProgress((int)((total*100)/size));
                                   fos.write(buffer,0, len1);   
                             }
                          }
                          if(fos != null){
                             fos.close();
                          }
                      }                     
                 }catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                        mue.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                           try {                
                             if(is != null){
                               is.close();
                             }
                           }catch (IOException ioe) {
                                 // just going to ignore this one
                           }
                }
                 return "";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String file_url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/93216523/stream?client_id=4346c8125f4f5c40ad666bacd8e96498";
```

DownLoad Class:

```
  private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(file_url);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(getOutputMediaFile());
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;           
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```